# How to find an item in a Redis queue

Tags: redis

I use Redis as my queuing engine, and now there are millions of items in my queue. I need to find an item there, and watch its properties.

If it was SQL Server or any type of RDBMS, I could use SQL language and execute a query against database to find the record. But in Redis queue, I can only push from one side, and pop from the same side, or the other side.

How can I do that?

Comment: I need more information to help you. What is the criteria to be used to find the item you want to select? Could you give an exemple of item you store in the list?

Answer (score 0):

With the vague nature of the question, we can only give you a vague answer.

You need to create secondary indexes to store find your data. As you already have it figured out that you cannot run SQL like queries therefore you should look at the following link

http://redis.io/topics/indexes

One important point that you should consider is the following (taken from the above link)

> Implementing and maintaining indexes with Redis is an advanced topic, so most users that need to perform complex queries on data should understand if they are better served by a relational store. However often, especially in caching scenarios, there is the explicit need to store indexed data into Redis in order to speedup common queries which require some form of indexing in order to be executed.